# Get value of Dictionary in Swift 3 which key isn't a String

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

I have a dictionary used NSIndexPath as key. It works fine with Swift 2 but I can't find a solution to make it work with Swift 3. I don't want to use String as a key so please don't suggest it.

```
// init
fileprivate var cachedCellSizes: [NSIndexPath: CGSize] = [:] 

// get value 
if let size = cachedCellSizes[indexPath] {
    return size
}
```

Compiler error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
```

Some solution I had tried but doesn't work:

```
if let size:CGSize = cachedCellSizes[indexPath] as? CGSize {
    return size
}
if let size:CGSize = cachedCellSizes[indexPath] as! CGSize {
    return size
}
if let size:CGSize = cachedCellSizes["indexPath"] as CGSize {
    return size
}
```

Comment: Please check that your indexPath is actually a `NSIndexPath`. Coz Swift 3 uses `IndexPath` (not `NSIndexPath`) in table delegate methods. If so you can use `if let size = cachedCellSizes[indexPath as! NSIndexPath]` or change dictionary key as `IndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileprivate var cachedCellSizes: [NSIndexPath: CGSize] = [:]

if let size = cachedCellSizes[indexPath as NSIndexPath] {
    print(indexPath)
}
```

OR

```
fileprivate var cachedCellSizes: [IndexPath: CGSize] = [:]

if let size = cachedCellSizes[indexPath] {
    print(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: The second method is preferable.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov is right, the second is preferable since you're using Swift 3.